# Execute function at future date/time even if website not in use?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, settimeout

Any ideas as to how I can set a function up so that it runs in a week's time whether or not the app is in use at that time? So far I have thought of using `window.setTimeout` but that is obviously dependent on the current browser session (to my understanding). I've also thought of a while loop but it seems like that would be a messy solution.

Any help would be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: You can't run Client-side JavaScript if the browser isn't running your app. For these kind of things you need some sort of Backend solution. **EDIT** Theoretically, you could use [localstorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) to fire your event as soon as the user opens your app after a week, if the user hasn't cleared his browser history the localstorage should still "live".

Comment: Are you talking about running client-side javascript at a specific time? Or is the javascript server-side? Are you using Node.js? It doesn't make any sense to run client-side code without a client. You need a server-side framework to do that, and you're server will need to be running for it to work.

Comment: The most straightforward method is good old Unix cron, which can run any kind of scripts that executes on the server (bash, Node, PHP, native binary...). But it's of course a 100% server-side solution.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as the browser loads another page or closes (tab or entirely), your script is stopped and get's unloaded.

Thus, you are unable to leave a "time bomb" for in a week, unless the user let's the page linger in the browser for that time at least.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution to dispatch an event on the client is to use a `ServiceWorker` and a push notification, but this is a very new and not widely adapter solution.